# Open/Close Popup with slide animation from custom position

Tags: c#, wpf

I wants to open Popup as slide animation from right side of the screen as shown in image below
[image]

Popup is placed on Right hand side of screen, and as off now Popup is open as usual w/o any animation.
Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I have tried it with DoubleAnimation and inside it I have provided valies From="0" To="-400" so that it animate from right to left. Here is a complete example I have tried
<DoubleAnimation 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" 
                From="0" To="-400" AutoReverse="false"/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done it with my logic, definitely its not a perfect answer but it is working.
What I have done is
1)Place Popup/Grid control outside the right side of my screen from where I have to open/close popup with animation[image]

So when I want to open my Popup I am adding ThicknessAnimation and my Popup/Grid animate to the portion(2) as shown in image, and while needs to remove Popup/Grid again I am applying ThicknessAnimation so that to move my Popup/Grid to portion (1) as shown
Here is my code.

```
//for opening Popup
myPopupGrid.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, -myPopupGrid.Width, 0);
ThicknessAnimation thicknessAnimation = new ThicknessAnimation();    
thicknessAnimation .From = myPopupGrid.Margin;    
thicknessAnimation .To = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
thicknessAnimation .Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
myPopupGrid.BeginAnimation(Grid.MarginProperty, thicknessAnimation );
thicknessAnimation .Completed += delegate { myPopupGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; }; 

//for closing Popup
myPopupGrid.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
ThicknessAnimation thicknessAnimation = new ThicknessAnimation();    
thicknessAnimation .From = myPopupGrid.Margin;    
thicknessAnimation .To = new Thickness(0, 0, -myPopupGrid.Width, 0);
thicknessAnimation .Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
myPopupGrid.BeginAnimation(Grid.MarginProperty, thicknessAnimation );
thicknessAnimation .Completed += delegate { myPopupGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; }; 

//Here point of notice is I am changing Thickness in both cases
//From
new Thickness(0, 0, -myPopupGrid.Width, 0)
//To
new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

and vice versa, which cause my Popup to reset his position To and from, thats it