# slide form behind windows in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, slide, drawer

Port this to WPF

[Slide form base Windos Forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1veu.gif)

I'm trying to port this to WPF, do you consider that this is possible to make in  WPF?

[Slide form base](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3390/A-Slide-Form-Base)

I´m test this:

[wpf-animation-how-do-i-make-it-slide-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51803869/wpf-animation-how-do-i-make-it-slide-in)

And this:

[open-close-popup-with-slide-animation-from-custom-position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148671/open-close-popup-with-slide-animation-from-custom-position)

I want to create a drawer like macosx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMzNS.png)

Comment: Hello, I managed to transfer this example to WPF, I don't know if it is the most effective way, but it worked for me. https://i.imgur.com/kBc7Mka.gif

Comment: `I want to create` - so what you've tried? You provide few examples, but which of them and how you implement? Where you stuck? In a short: in WPF to "slide" window you should use `DoubleAnimation` over window location properties (Top, Left, etc). Expanded answer can't be provided without understanding what you've done and what you can't deal with

Comment: Hi @Auditive I try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51803869/wpf-animation-how-do-i-make-it-slide-in

Comment: The goal is this: https://i.imgur.com/kBc7Mka.gif

Comment: As you can say, I think that DoubleAnimation is the better option

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're after the effect you showed on the first gif on the Winforms, where the drawer slides from underneath the form, to achieve similar effect on WPF there's a couple of possible problems you need to deal with.

First of all, in order to see the drawer *outside* the `Window` you need to set `AllowTransparency` to True and `WindowStyle` to None.

That's the first problem, cause you're now missing the default Window functionalities like Minimize, Maximize, Drag and Close. Not to mention that now there's also Window default `DropShadow` effect missing, and if you'd like to have it anyway, you need to create it yourself.

Second of all, *responsivness*, since `WindowStyle` is None, there's also missing Resize functionality of the `Window`. If you'd like to bring it back, there's even bigger problem cause now, you need to take great care of the layout and make sure all the values of the `RenderTransform.TranslateLayout` are correct in order to move the drawer to desired values when the size of the Window would change.

With all that said, here's my proposal, how the *slide effect* can be achieved.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp8"
        Title="MainWindow"
        WindowStyle="None"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        Background="Transparent"
        mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Width="400" Height="400">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="TransformBorder">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="movingBorder"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                               Duration="0:0:0.3">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="400">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Border x:Name="movingBorder"
                Background="LightBlue"
                RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Border.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="translateTransform" X="0" Y="0"/>
            </Border.RenderTransform>
        </Border>

        <Border Background="White">
            <Button x:Name="btnSlide"
                    Width="100"
                    Height="50"
                    Content="Slide"/>
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"
                                  Opacity="0.5"
                                  BlurRadius="20"
                                  Color="Black"/>
            </Border.Effect>
        </Border>

        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="btnSlide">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource TransformBorder}"/>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

https://imgur.com/LB7EVEo